# LDAP search filter

Tags: filter, ldap

I have the following structure coming from my LDAP when I use this filter :

**(objectclass=bussoapprocessor)** .

```
<data>
<GetSoapProcessorsResponse>
    <tuple>
        <old>
            <entry dn="cn=ABC" entryUUID="5ec82981-d111-4851-98cc-0ff7fd40c977">
                <bussoapprocessorconfiguration>
                    <string>
                        <configurations autoStartCount="3">
                            <cancelReplyInterval>30000</cancelReplyInterval>
                            <gracefulCompleteTime>15</gracefulCompleteTime>
                            <abortTime>5</abortTime>

                            <routing ui_type="loadbalancing" ui_algorithm="failover">
                                <preference>1</preference>
                            </routing>
                            <configuration implementation="applicationconnector.uddi.UDDIConnector" htmfile="/uddi/applicationconnector/uddi.caf">

                                <startupDependency xmlns="http://schemas.abc.com/1.0/xmlstore">
                                    <namespace>http://schemas.abc.com/1.0/xmlstore</namespace>
                                </startupDependency>
                                <isProxyEnabled>false</isProxyEnabled>
                                <advancedoptions>
                                    <ignorecert>false</ignorecert>
                                    <so_timeout>1800000</so_timeout>
                                </advancedoptions>
                            </configuration>

                        </configurations>
                    </string>
                </bussoapprocessorconfiguration>
                <computer>
                    <string>mycomp</string>
                </computer>
                <automaticstart>
                    <string>true</string>
                </automaticstart>

                <objectclass>
                    <string>top</string>
                    <string>bussoapprocessor</string>
                </objectclass>
            </entry>
        </old>
    </tuple>
    <tuple>
        <old>
            <entry dn="ABC 2">
                <bussoapprocessorconfiguration>
                    <string>
                        <configurations autoStartCount="3">
                            <cancelReplyInterval>30000</cancelReplyInterval>
                            <gracefulCompleteTime>15</gracefulCompleteTime>
                            <abortTime>5</abortTime>
                            <jreconfig>
                                <param value="-Xmx256M"/>
                                <param value="-XX:PermSize=5m"/>
                            </jreconfig>
                            <routing ui_type="loadbalancing" ui_algorithm="failover">
                                <preference>1</preference>
                            </routing>
                            <configuration implementation="com.eibus.applicationconnector.sap.SAPMapper" htmfile="/bac/sap/sap.htm">
                                <classpath>
                                    <location>/BAC/SAP/lib/sapjco.jar</location>
                                    <location>/BAC/SAP/lib/sapidocjco.jar</location>
                                    <location>/BAC/SAP/lib/sapidoc.jar</location>
                                    <location>/BAC/SAP/lib/jdsr.jar</location>
                                    <location>/BAC/SAP/lib/coelib.jar</location>
                                    <location>/BAC/SAP/lib/wsdl4j.jar</location>
                                    <location>/BAC/SAP/sapconnector.jar</location>

                            </configuration>
                        </configurations>
                    </string>
                </bussoapprocessorconfiguration>
                <computer>
                    <string>mycomp</string>
                </computer>
                <automaticstart>
                    <string>true</string>
                </automaticstart>
                <cn>
                    <string>SAP R3 Connector</string>
                </cn>
                <objectclass>
                    <string>top</string>
                    <string>bussoapprocessor</string>
                </objectclass>
            </entry>
        </old>
    </tuple>
    </GetSoapProcessorsResponse>
```

I want to fetch that entry which has the implementation as "com.eibus.applicationconnector.sap.SAPMapper". Kindly suggest how I can make the query for the filtering according to the implementation attribute in the configuration tag? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the underlying LDAP directory server, (which you do not mention, but I would guess is neither eDirectory nor Active Directory, so probably OIM or Sun Directory server) has the schema for this attribute defined that it supports wildcard substring searches then there is a possible way.

You also do not mention the name of the attribute this data is stored in.

But if wildcards are supported then adding a filter of

```
(UnNamedAttribute=*implementation="com.eibus.applicationconnector.sap.SAPMapper*)
```

But since you probably also want only this class, more completely:

```
(&(objectclass=bussoapprocessor)(UnNamedAttribute=*implementation="com.eibus.applicationconnector.sap.SAPMapper*))
```